# Social Media link repeats itself when in multiple div tags

Tags: html, css

I need to add social media links to a page but they repeat themselves many times.  I found that it has to do with how many nested div tags it resides in.  For example, this one repeats itself 4 times:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>
<body >
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <a class="fa fa-facebook" href="#" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

I found the code for this here:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_social_media_buttons.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you forgot to close the "a" tag.

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>
<body >
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <a class="fa fa-facebook" href="#" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmmm.  Thank you.  Actually I didn't forget.  I thought that if you didn't need to put anything between the starting and end tag that you could just close of the starting tag with a "/>"  it works perfect now.  Thanks again!